# Instantiating class throws uninitialized constant error

Tags: ruby, libgosu

so ive made 2 classes the grass inherits from the Tile class, anytime the Tile class is called it should go to the grass class and create a tile containing itself. the problem is i get "uninitialized constant Tile::Grass (name error)" and im not sure why, if anyone has any insight please help me out!

```
require_relative './Assets.rb'
require_relative './Tile.rb'

class Grass < Tile
  def initialize id
    Tile.new Assets.grass, id
  end

  def isSolid
    return false
  end
end



require './Grass.rb'

class Tile
  class << self
    def tiles(id)
      return @@Tiles[id]
    end
  end
  @@Tiles = []
  @@GrassTile = Grass.new(0)

  def initialize asset, id
    @@Tiles[id] = self;
  end

  def update
  end

  def draw
  end
end
```

Comment: What's in your loaded scripts? I'm assuming you should have `Tile` defined in one of those?

Comment: im calling Tile.tiles(0) in my game.rb file but im never instantiating Tile.new under the impression that Grass.new would also create a new Tile object

Comment: most of my experience comes from c# and some java so i could be doing things not the Ruby way

Comment: what is the load order? It seems like a circular dependency .. Grass inherits from Tile but Tile uses Grass in its defiinition.

Comment: i think youre correct thats the issue, circular dependancy, any tips on how i could implement a tile manager?

Comment: Maybe `require_relative './Grass.rb'` instead of `require './Grass.rb'`

Comment: it returned the same error, i gave up on doing it this way and took a different approach though id still love a definite answer

Comment: Provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to increase your chances of receiving an answer. Ping me, if you update your question.